# What is this build error with react native ios simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

My app was running in the iOS simulator with no problems.

It then randomly fails to build with an error.

When I run `npx react-native run-ios`

It shows error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-fhebctengshjldchmuocojqrncuz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTActionSheetManager.o /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/testapp/node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules/RCTActionSheetManager.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-CoreModules' from project 'Pods')
```

What is this error and what does it mean?

Comment: make sure the name in package.json, package-lock.json and app.json is the project name and the same